# How to use PublisherServiceAsyncClient

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to use AsyncPublisherClient from pubsublite

```
pip install google-cloud-pubsublite==1.8.3
```

```
from google.cloud import pubsublite_v1

pubsub = pubsublite_v1.AsyncPublisherClient()
```

> error: Module has no attribute "AsyncPublisherClient"

The documentation is very scarce and I couldn't even find this class in the virtualenv directory, just its interface.

### How do I use this library?

EDIT: It looks like the correct class is `PublisherServiceAsyncClient`

---

EDIT2:

```
from google.cloud.pubsublite_v1.types.publisher import PublishRequest
from google.cloud.pubsublite_v1.types import PubSubMessage
from google.cloud.pubsublite_v1 import PublisherServiceAsyncClient

pubsub = PublisherServiceAsyncClient()

message = PubSubMessage(data=json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8"))

request = PublishRequest(topic=os.environ["TOPIC"], messages=[message])

async def request_generator():
    yield request

await pubsub.publish(requests=request_generator())
```

> ValueError: Unknown field for PublishRequest: topic

Answer (score 2):

In [google.cloud.pubsublite](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.pubsublite.v1), the topic path is typically specified in the routing information or elsewhere in the client's configuration.

Initialize `PublisherServiceAsyncClient` without specifying the topic path directly.
The topic must be specified through the proper configuration or routing setup, which is often done separately from the `PublishRequest`.

```py
from google.cloud.pubsublite_v1 import PublisherServiceAsyncClient
from google.cloud.pubsublite_v1.types import PubSubMessage, PublishRequest
import os
import json

# Initialize the PublisherServiceAsyncClient
pubsub = PublisherServiceAsyncClient()

# Prepare your message
payload = {"your": "data"}  # Replace with your actual payload
message = PubSubMessage(data=json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8"))

# Create a PublishRequest (without specifying the topic)
request = PublishRequest(messages=[message])

async def request_generator():
    yield request

# Publish the message
await pubsub.publish(requests=request_generator())
```

That assumes that the Pub/Sub Lite environment (including topics and possibly subscriptions) is already correctly set up and that the `PublisherServiceAsyncClient` can interact with this setup.
The exact way to specify the topic in the client's configuration depends on your environment and setup. That can vary based on how you manage resources in Google Cloud Pub/Sub Lite.

Comment: Thank you, but `pubsublite_v1` does not have `PublisherOptions` class. I had to import from `from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.types import PublisherOptions` and it not worked. I am sure that I have the latest version of pubsublite, which is `google-cloud-pubsublite==1.8.3`

Comment: From `PublisherServiceAsyncClient`, client_options is  ClientOptions, not PublisherOptions. Reference: `client_options: Optional[ClientOptions] = None`

Comment: TypeError: PublisherOptions.__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'topic_path'

Comment: @Rodrigo OK, thank you for the clarification. I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't think this will work, I got the error `ValueError: Unknown field for PublishRequest: topic_path`.

Comment: @Rodrigo Sorry, I was looking at the wrong documentation (google-cloud-pubsub instead of google.cloud.pubsublite!). I have rewritten the answer from what I understand of the google.cloud.pubsublite documentation. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I gave up, I don't know why I insist on using Google Cloud. I can't test your solution right now because I migrated the code, but I find it strange that the topic doesn't fit in anywhere.